# Code signing error on iOS Simulator

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

I am using XCode 3.2.6 with iPhone Simulator 4.3 but when i run build and run this app on iPhone Simulator it throws error

**Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain**

I got to know about this error when i am using Interface Builder->Build and go to XCode
then it shows error and when compiled using XCode it just shows a blank screen on iPhone Simulator.

Comment: did you change the settings in targets.like select the provisioning profile

Answer (score 0):

It may be helpful to you.

```
   1. Select the target under Groups & Files
   2.Click the Get Info button
   3.Choose the Properties tab
   4.Under Identifier, make sure it says com.YOURREALCOMPANYNAME.APPNAME
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have created proper developer profile and installed it in Keychain.
Lso check your bundle identifier

Hope it works....